# Can't POST an array of string to ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an **MVC3** controller action:

```
public ActionResult DoStuff(DoStuffModel model)
```

The `DoStuffModel` looks like this:

```
public class DoStuffModel
{
    public long SomeId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

In my jQuery I do this:

```
 var postData = {
     SomeId: 1,
     Codes: ["code1", "code2", "code3"]
 };

$.post(url, postData, function (data) {});
```

The URL is correct. The `postData` looks like this when I log it:

[image]

The `SomeId` gets bound correctly, but `Codes` remains null. What is going on?

Comment: Your model expects an array called Codes, but in your dev-tools it shows that in the javascript object the array name is PiCodes. Can you check if that helps?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried `public string[] Codes { get; set; }`

Comment: Bad screenshotting on my part, sorry. The names correspond though.

Comment: please set application content-type = "application/json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `$.ajax()` method and set the correct ajax options and stringify your data.

The `$.post()` method is sending the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, which means you would need to generate the collection with indexers in order for the `DefaultModelBinder` to bind it - for example

```
var postData = { SomeId: 1, 'Codes[0]': 'code1', 'Codes[1]': 'code2', 'Codes[2]': 'code3'};
```

The code using your current object containing an array would be

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ model: postData })
    success: function(data) {
        ....
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, `[0].Codes` does not appear to be correct syntax. My Intellisense seems to complain about it at least.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the quotes (note you can also use `'Codes[0]'` in this case (collection of simple objects)

Comment: Since you are sending JSON you don't need to be using `Codes[0]`. The OPs original `postData` was correct, he was just missing the `application/json` header.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I know - I was explaining how the data would need to be generated without setting the `contentType` option :)

Comment: Thanks. However, neither of your options seems to work at all. Not even `SomeId` gets bound this way.

Comment: Have just tested both options using your model and both options bind correctly.

Comment: Took some extra effort on my end, but this is the correct solution. Thanks for your time!